# How do I sort two columns against one in Excel 2003?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I need to produce a method of moving the B and C columns to match up with A so:

[image]

with a macro or formula it should produce:

[image]

Column 1(A) should be unchanged but 2(B) and 3(C) moved; 2 and 3 will also need to be linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the range represented by B1:C11 in your top screen capture to reflect the range of B and C columns. Move the B & C column content to another location such as G1:H11

Then in B1

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$G$1:$H$11,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"",VLOOKUP(A1,$G$1:$H$11,1,FALSE))
```

and in C1

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$G$1:$H$11,2,FALSE))=TRUE,"",VLOOKUP(A1,$G$1:$H$11,2,FALSE))
```

you can always insert name define the range $G$1:$H$11 (or whatever it is) and use the namedRange in the formulas instead which would look like

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,namedRange,1,FALSE))=TRUE,"",VLOOKUP(A1,namedRange,1,FALSE))
```

and

```
 =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,namedRange,2,FALSE))=TRUE,"",VLOOKUP(A1,namedRange,2,FALSE))
```

of course drag the formulas in B1 and C1 down adjacent to column A.

Comment: Brillant! Thank you very much, you saved my keyboard from a window excursion.